# What is this four-player card game with only Jacks, Queens, Kings, and Aces?

Tags: identify-this-game

Deck dealt contains only Jack, Queen, King, Ace. Four players. Each player gives one card to his neighbour in each round. Each player tries to get pairs and gets rid of them. Once one person is finished, everyone tries to put his hand on the pile of cards (the cards not used in the deck, penalty cards) in the middle of the table.

The last one has to take the penalty card.

Answer (score 3):

In my family (Austria), it is called "HAUSDEPP". So it lasts a little longer than EZEL ;)

We dont place a hand in the center, but have #numer_of_players-1 walnuts in the center of the table, and everyone needs to grab one, as soon as one player reaches 4 equals and grabs the first.

Apparently, the game is "well known" under that name. Could not find official rules, but several references. You can also take bottle caps in the center:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/28527236@N05/3361355864

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dutch game "[ezelen](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezelen)" (There is probably an English name but I haven't found it. Ezel is the dutch word for donkey.

There are 4 cards per player. They pass a card each round and the goal is to get 4 of the same kind (for example 4 jacks). If you get four, you put your thumb on the table. And the other players must also put the thumb on the tabel. The last one gets a letter (first 'E', then 'Z' until you have the word "EZEL" and lost the game).

Comment: When I played this we used to put our thumb on the edge of the table as casually as possible, as not to alert the other players.